# Please take a look at my code. Trying to plot multiple points on a map (with labels) & failing miserably

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

First, I apologize that this is probably a completely obvious question. I am not very familiar with Javascript, and purchased a really nice theme for my nonprofit that uses it to create a Google Map. You can see it here [ [test2013.moconj.org](http://test2013.moconj.org) ] I did not write the code. It works beautifully, but now I have to figure out how to modify it a little and that's where I am hoping you can help me.

I just need to know what parts of it I should be touching without breaking the map, as that seems to be all I can accomplish when I'm doing this on my own! I need to be able to input several addresses, at the very least with labels, though pop-up info would be even better. Thank you for your help!

There are two files that contribute to the code in question:

**The map-related code in my index (.html) file:**

`<div id="map-canvas" lat="40.349176" long="-74.07052"></div>`

**The bulk of the map code is in another (.js) file:**

```
 map: function() {
            var mapCanvas = $('#map-canvas'), mapMaker;
            var coords = {
                lat: mapCanvas.attr('lat') ? mapCanvas.attr('lat') : 40.349176,
                long: mapCanvas.attr('long') ? mapCanvas.attr('long') : -74.07052,
            };

            // No map canvas present
            if (!mapCanvas.length) {
                return;
            }

            // Google Map
            var map;

            // Create an array of styles
            var styles = [
                {   
                    stylers: [
                        {hue: options.color },
                        {saturation: -30 },
                        {lightness: -10 },
                    ]
                },{
                    featureType: "road",
                    elementType: "geometry",
                    stylers: [
                        {lightness: 100 },
                        {visibility: "simplified" },
                    ]
                },{
                    featureType: "road",
                    elementType: "labels",
                    stylers: [
                        {visibility: "off"},
                    ]
                }
            ];

            // Create a new StyledMapType object
            var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
                styles,
                {name: "Styled Map"}
            );

            // Map Coordinates
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.long);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: myLatlng,
                scrollwheel: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            // Create the actual map
            map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas[0], mapOptions);

            // Marker Coordinates
            mapMaker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.long),
                map: map
            });

            map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
            map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

this will create a marker

```
// Marker Coordinates
mapMaker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.long),
    map: map
    title : 'whatever' // add title to your marker 
});
```

this will make your markers clickable

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

and with this one you tell what info window to open

```
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });
```

**EDIT:**
to answer you comment

you currently have 1 point declared

```
 lat="40.349176" long="-74.07052"
```

but if you want to display more then 1 marker . then you need 1 point for each marker

its kinda ugly to add markers position as `data-attr` inside the HTML . but you can make an array inside the JS

this will look something like this

```
var markersPosition = [
  {
    lat: xx1.xxx
    lng: yy1.yyyy
  },
  {
    lat: xx2.xxx
    lng: yy2.yyyy
  },
  {
    lat: xx3.xxx
    lng: yy3.yyyy
  },
]
```

then . when you create your markers . you do it based on the number of 'locations' from you `markersPosition` array

```
for (var i = o; i < markersPositon.length; i++) {
  mapMaker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(markersPositon[i].lat, markersPositon[i].lng),
      map: map
      title : 'whatever' // add title to your marker 
  });
}
```

- this code . copy-pasted . i don't think it will work :( . if you make a fiddle i can add the missing part in there

Comment: Perfect! I see just where it needs to go. Thank you. One quick question, but what about the .html file? Right now there is just the one set of coordinates. Do I just leave it alone? I wasn't sure if that was just a starting point for the map, or if the coordinates need to be the same as the .js file.

Comment: each marker should have its own coords ... that means . you need to change 'LatLng(coords.lat, coords.long)' .. different for each marker

Comment: So, to make sure I'm clear on what I need to do...if this is what I have now in the html file: <div id="map-canvas" lat="40.349176" long="-74.07052"></div> (that is all the code that is in that file) then what would that look like with multiple points? Does each lat/long set get its own div? Can you show me just a quick example of how you would fix that?... I'm sure this is a painfully obvious anwer. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: I created this fiddle with my original code. Haven't had a chance to add what you suggested yet: http://jsfiddle.net/qRN9e/ Thank you for your clear answers. I'm trying to help out my organization, but am in way over my head with this!

Comment: Actually, I was able to create a fiddle with what I hope you were telling me to do: http://jsfiddle.net/qRN9e/1/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this comment before for some reason! I would have answered you earlier :) I admit, I had no idea what you were talking about with fiddles (thank goodness for google), and now I see I didn't share it correctly either. Sorry!! Here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/qRN9e/2/  I'm sure it's obvious by now that I am in waay over my head, and I really appreciate your patience with this!